# Filtering records in app-engine (Java)

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have following code running perfectly. It filter records based on single parameter.

```
 public List<Orders> GetOrders(String email)
  {
   PersistenceManager pm = PMF.get().getPersistenceManager();
   Query query = pm.newQuery(Orders.class); 
      query.setFilter("Email == pEmail"); 
      query.setOrdering("Id desc"); 
      query.declareParameters("String pEmail");
      query.setRange(0,50);      
   return (List<Orders>) query.execute(email);
  }
```

Now i want to filter on multiple parameters. sdate and edate is Start Date and End Date. 
In datastore it is saved as Date (not String).

```
public List<Orders> GetOrders(String email,String icode,String sdate, String edate)
  {
   PersistenceManager pm = PMF.get().getPersistenceManager();
   Query query = pm.newQuery(Orders.class); 
      query.setFilter("Email == pEmail");
      query.setFilter("ItemCode == pItemCode");
      query.declareParameters("String pEmail");
      query.declareParameters("String pItemCode");
               .....//Set filter and declare other 2 parameters
               .....// 
               ......
      query.setRange(0,50);      
      query.setOrdering("Id desc");
   return (List<Orders>) query.execute(email,icode,sdate,edate);
  }
```

Any clue?

---

My first problem is solved. But still have some problem

1: How I can filter by Date parameter (Getting as string in jsp) ?

2: The query.execute() method support upto 3 parameters. Is it possible to pass more?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use multiple SetFilter() to setup multiple conditions. You must use a single if-like condition, so it will be

```
query.setFilter("Email == pEmail && ItemCode == pItemCode");
```

same for declareParameters with a comma-separeted list as follows

```
Query.declareParameters("String pEmail, String pItemCode");
```

Comment: yeah it works.. Thanks..

What about Date parameter? and what if i need to pass more than 3 parameter? It only support upto 3 parameters.

Comment: If you need more than 3 parameters, you can use the query.executeWithMap API and pass a hash map of key/values for your parameters. For example map.put("param_name_1", param_1_value);